# Raise different events if a textbox is focused or not

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I'm working on this page:

[image]

How it works: the "Consultar" button searches for the code in the "Código" textbox and reloads the page. The "Salvar" button calls a routine to save what you have changed in that item.

Here's what I gotta do: if the "Código" textbox is focused and the user press Enter, the event of the "Consultar" button must be raised. If the "Código" textbox is not focused and the user press Enter, the event of the "Salvar" button must be raised.

I don't know how to do this, I tried to do this using SetDefault button but it won't work cause I need a different button to be default depending if the textbox is focused or not.
I wonder I that I'll probably have to use some javascript, but I have no clue about how to do it.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind an event handler to the keypress event on your document and then check if the input field is focused. If so, you can submit your search form, otherwise you continue with your saving logic.

See this fiddle to see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/KkJ2t/

Comment: Hi Felix, I've tried this but the condition if($("#searchInput").is(":focus")) is always returning true, no mather what control is focused.