# is(":focus") always returning true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841350/raise-different-events-if-a-textbox-is-focused-or-not) because of something I need to and I'm having some problems with jQuery. So I'm opening this question 'cause others may have this too.

In the answer posted in my other question, the user Felix tells me to do something like this:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(e.which == 13 ) {
        if($("#searchInput").is(":focus")) {
          alert("search form submitted");
          return false;
        } else {
          alert("save form submitted");                  
          return false;
        }
    }
});
​
```

That seems to be what I need, however, the condition `if($("#searchInput").is(":focus"))` is **always** returning True, no mather what control is focused.

Anyone has a clue why this might be happening or any other way I could do this?

Comment: you might want to check jquery version . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967096/using-jquery-to-test-if-an-input-has-focus

Comment: that' s working fine as expected on http://jsfiddle.net/KkJ2t/

Comment: Yeap...my jQuery version was out of date. Answer the question so I can accept it.

Comment: @devGabriel You should answer the question yourself an afterwards accept it…

Comment: Can you share your html code it will be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My jQuery version was out of date, I just got the latest version from [here](http://jquery.com/download/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=Downloading_jQuery&redirect=no) and now that code is running ok.

Comment: and dev make sure that your other module is not getting affected due to change in library.i wrote validation for all controls.when i upgraded my library from 1.4.1 to 1.8.2 i saw weird behavior of some controls not following proper validation.

Comment: Right, I'll check that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It might have been caused by older version of jquery used.
If it's older than 1.6 then `:focus` won't work if you havent defined it.
Version 1.6 and further have the `:focus` selector, we don't have to define it separately.
So just upgrade your library version if it's old or define `:focus` somewhere in your js file. Check api for 1.6 here:
[jquery version 1.6](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.6/)

Answer (score 2):

Your jQuery version might be out of date.  Get the latest version with:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```